# UWP Application - Will it possible to delete the submission after the published on the store

Tags: uwp

UWP application(Hybrid) has published and released in store. The version is 3.5. I want to revert or delete that submission(3.5).

Does it allow to do it?
is it retain the previous version 3.4 automatically ? will it possible to do?
If it not possible to delete the 3.5. version, will it allow to upload the same 3.4 version as 3.6 in store?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Microsoft Store does not support version rollback. Simply put, the version number can only be increased but not decreased, and the released package cannot be replaced.

So you need to upload a package with version number 3.6 to "update", this has nothing to do with the contents of your package, so you can roll back the application code, but the re-build package needs to be a higher version.